# writing to a dataframe from a for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I'm trying to write from a loop to a data frame in R, for example a loop like this>

```
for (i in 1:20) {
print(c(i+i,i*i,i/1))}
```

and to write each line of 3 values to a data frame with three columns, so that each iteration takes on a new row. I've tried using matrix, with ncol=3 and filled by rows, but only get the last item from the loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

You could use rbind:

```
d <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:20) {d <- rbind(d,c(i+i, i*i, i/1))}
```

Comment: Note that this is probably the least efficient solution proposed.  For very small data sets it won't matter too much but you really shouldn't be using rbind or cbind inside a loop if you want to be efficient.

Answer (score 10):

Another way would be

```
do.call("rbind", sapply(1:20, FUN = function(i) c(i+i,i*i,i/1), simplify = FALSE))


     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    2    1    1
 [2,]    4    4    2
 [3,]    6    9    3
 [4,]    8   16    4
 [5,]   10   25    5
 [6,]   12   36    6
```

If you don't specify `simplify = FALSE`, you have to transpose the result using `t`. This can be tedious for large structures.

This solution is especially handy if you have a data set on the large side and/or you need to repeat this many many times.

I offer some timings of solutions in this "thread".

```
> system.time(do.call("rbind", sapply(1:20000, FUN = function(i) c(i+i,i*i,i/1), simplify = FALSE)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.00    0.05 

> system.time(ldply(1:20000, function(i)c(i+i, i*i, i/1)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.14    0.00    0.14 

> system.time({d <- matrix(nrow=20000, ncol=3) 
+ for (i in 1:20000) { d[i,] <- c(i+i, i*i, i/1)}})
   user  system elapsed 
   0.10    0.00    0.09 

> system.time(ldply(1:20000, function(i)c(i+i, i*i, i/1)))
   user  system elapsed 
  62.88    0.00   62.99
```

Comment: `sapply` seems to have gotten faster (on my machine at least) when writing it as sapply(**1:2e4**, FUN = function(i) **c(2*i,i^2,i/1)**, simplify = FALSE)

Answer (score 6):

`For` loops have side-effects, so the usual way of doing this is to create an empty dataframe before the loop and then add to it on each iteration. You can instantiate it to the correct size and then assign your values to the `i`'th row on each iteration, or else add to it and reassign the whole thing using `rbind()`.

The former approach will have better performance for large datasets.

Comment: Thanks for both these answers, to assign values to the ith row do you mean something like this, (this doesn't actually work). Also, would this way work with a dataframe with unknown no of rows?

    rm(d)
    d <- data.frame(nrow=20, ncol=3)
    for (i in 1:20) {
    d[i,] <- c(i+i, i*i, i/1)}

Comment: Why did you say "unknown no of rows" when your example has i in 1:20?  If there are unknown number of rows, you'll need to use something like rbind as another answer suggests.

Answer (score 6):

If all your values have the same type and you know the number of rows, you can use a matrix in the following way (this will be very fast):

```
d <- matrix(nrow=20, ncol=3) 
for (i in 1:20) { d[i,] <- c(i+i, i*i, i/1)}
```

If you need a data frame, you can use rbind (as another answer suggests), 
or functions from package plyr like this:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(1:20, function(i)c(i+i, i*i, i/1))
```