# Copy specific rows of a dataframe to a new dataframe, using FOR loop in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (called crossID) of 100 rows and 65 columns. This dataframe can contain duplicates, but these duplicates are contiguously (I mean, if row 31 has a duplicate, the duplicate will be in row 32, and only there).

I simply want to extract the non-duplicated rows and copy them in a new dataframe (I called crossID_clean). And I want to extract the duplicated rows and put them in another dataframe (I called crossDup)

I wrote this code:

```
crossID_clean = data.frame()
crossDup = data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(crossID)){
  if(crossID[i,1] != crossID[i+1,1]){
     crossID_clean = rbind(crossID_clean, crossID[i,])
     ncross=ncross+1  #good crossmatches
   }else{
    crossDup = rbind(crossDup, crossID[i,]) #List of duplicated crossmatches
    ndel = ndel+1   #objects deleted because having more than one crossmatch
  }
}
```

which ends-up with an error:

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

I don't get where is the problem, since the two new dataframes have no specified columns, so I think that there could not be a problem of "number of columns"...

I read how to create dataframes within a loop and how to append rows to a new dataframe in other posts, but all what I found is when using 1 dataframe (like in [writing to a dataframe from a for-loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563824/writing-to-a-dataframe-from-a-for-loop-in-r)) , and not by playing with two or more dataframes. Sorry, if there's already a post with this. I will appreciate so much your help.

Thanks.

Comment: As is quite often the case in R, a `for` loop is not a good approach for this and there is a specialized function you can use. Read `help("duplicated")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `duplicated`?

```
set.seed(3)

L3 <- LETTERS[1:3]
d <- data.frame(
  v1 = sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE),
  v2 = sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE),
  v3 = sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE)
  )

d_dupl <- d[duplicated(d[,1]),]
d_nondupl <- d[!duplicated(d[,1]),]
```

Comment: (+1) judging from his code he seems to only take into account the first field for identifying a duplicate

Comment: Thanks so much, it works very well and very fast :) But, I'm still curious to know what is wrong in my code, why I'm getting that error. Just to learn about my own errors! Any idea will be appreciated, but thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: Without seeing your data, one can't be sure but try replacing `crossID_clean = data.frame()
crossDup = data.frame()` with `crossID_clean = crossID[0,]
crossDup = crossID[0,]`. Also, consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: I tried what you told me, but it gives the same error. I know that without seeing the data is much more difficult, but I think that in that case putting just a subset of it (since it is so big) will not help so much. Don't worry, your solution works fine and it's very nice and clean. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For dataframe d, how about:

```
unique(d)           # uniques
d[duplicated(d),]   # duplicates
```

or obviously if you do want to pull out based on ONLY the first column as per the code (or column 'i'), but not sure why that would be useful

```
d[unique(d[,1]),]
d[duplicated(d[,1]),]
```

Comment: Thank you Troy. As I said above, it works perfect with "duplicate". The fact of specifying the column is just that in the case of my data it's enough to validate that the values in the first column are repeated. In some cases the rest of columns could not be equal, but I don't care about it.