# How do you write to a data.frame when one of your columns contains strings?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

My question contains a variation of code found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2564029/109941).

The folllowing code:

```
d <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:3) {d <- rbind(d,c(i+i, i*i, i/1))}
d
str(d)
```

Generates the following output:

```
  X2 X1 X1.1
1  2  1    1
2  4  4    2
3  6  9    3

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X2  : num  2 4 6
 $ X1  : num  1 4 9
 $ X1.1: num  1 2 3
```

But this code:

```
d2 <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:3) {d2 <- rbind(d2,c(i+i, i*i, i/1, "foo"))}
d2
str(d2)
```

Generates the wrong output:

```
   X.2. X.1. X.1..1 X.foo.
1    2    1      1    foo
2 <NA> <NA>   <NA>    foo
3 <NA> <NA>   <NA>    foo

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X.2.  : Factor w/ 1 level "2": 1 NA NA
 $ X.1.  : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 NA NA
 $ X.1..1: Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 NA NA
 $ X.foo.: Factor w/ 1 level "foo": 1 1 1
```

And it generates errors too:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "4") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "4") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "2") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "6") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
5: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "9") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
6: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "3") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smallest change to your code is to change `c` to `data.frame`:

```
d2 <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:3) {d2 <- rbind(d2, data.frame(i+i, i*i, i/1, "foo"))}
d2
str(d2)
```

but in general vectorized approach is better.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create your data row-wise using a `for` loop. Instead, use vectorized functions to create the data column-wise:

```
x <- 1:3
data.frame(a = x+x, b = x*x, c = x/1, d = "foo")
#  a b c   d
#1 2 1 1 foo
#2 4 4 2 foo
#3 6 9 3 foo
```

In this case, column `d` is a length 1 vector which is being recycled to fit the length of the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have mentioned, using concatenation inside a loop is a bad way of building an object since it’s very slow.

However, to explain why your code doesn’t work, consider what `c` does here: it constructs a vector. However, vectors in R are *homogenenous containers*, meaning they can only contain a single data type.

In your case, this leads to the numbers being coerced to character strings. So that, in the first iteration of the loop, the result would be:

```
c('2', '1', '1', 'foo')
```

Next, this vector is conatenated as a new row to your data.frame. However, by default character vectors are converted to `factor`s inside a `data.frame`. Hence the result after the first iteration is the following data.frame:

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X.2.  : Factor w/ 1 level "2": 1
 $ X.1.  : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1
 $ X.1..1: Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1
 $ X.foo.: Factor w/ 1 level "foo": 1
```

Note that all columns are factors. And all have only one level: `2`, `1`, `1` and `foo`, respectively. Now, when you concatenate another row in the next loop iteration, `cbind` coerces the new vector to the factors already found inside `d2`. For `'foo'`, this works. But for the other numbers, this doesn’t work, because the factors don’t contain the necessary levels. Hence, the result of the coercion is `NA`.

Comment: This is a very well written explanation of what's actually happen. I just need a little guidance about how to get from here to there.